# I'm trying to use latex to generate pdf and svg formats of the pictures I made, but the useage of the dvisvgm tool will make my pdf file look weird

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, svg, dvisvgm

##### Thank you for reading my question

#### Introduction

---

My latex compile environment is **VSCode + Texlive + LaTeX workshop.**

---

I want to use the **tikz** toolkit in latex to draw some pictures and generate **.pdf**  and **.svg**  of the pictures. The tool **dvisvgm** is used to generate svg format pictures.
My idea is that the **.pdf** is compiled and generated directly by ***XeLaTeX***, while the **.svg** is generated as follows: **first**, ***LaTex*** compiles the **.tex** file to **.dvi** file, and then use the ***dvisvgm*** tool to compile the **.dvi** file to **.svg** file.
The following is my compilation environment configuration (only the compilation methods I use are listed)：

#### latex tools

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "dvisvgm",
            "command": "dvisvgm",
            "args": [
                // "-synctex=1",
                // "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                // "-file-line-error",
                // "-pdf",
                "%DOCFILE%.dvi"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latex",
            "command": "latex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
    ],
```

#### latex recipes

```json
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "XeLaTeX",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "LaTeX",
            "tools": [
                "latex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "DviSvgm",
            "tools": [
                "dvisvgm"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "XeLaTeX -> LaTeX -> DviSvgm",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex",
                "latex",
                "dvisvgm"
            ]
        },
    ],
```

#### Problem Decription

I found the following problem when executing my idea. The following is my code and results:

#### my code

```latex
\documentclass[dvisvgm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usetikzlibrary{...}% tikz package already loaded by 'tikz' option
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Draw a circle
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
% Draw a rectangle
\draw (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
% Draw an arrow
\draw[->] (6,1) -- (8,1);
% Label some points
\node at (0,0) [below] {Center};
\node at (4,1) {Rectangle};
\node at (7,1) [above] {Arrow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The compilation method is: XeLaTeX -> LaTeX -> DviSvgm**

### The following is my output file:

#### my .pdf

[image: my .pdf]

#### my .svg(in visio)

[image: my .svg(in visio)]

***The pdf file looks completely wrong!***

---

### In my continuous efforts, I found the following results:

#### The following is my modified code and the final result

(I deleted the ***dvisvgm*** in the options):

#### my code

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usetikzlibrary{...}% tikz package already loaded by 'tikz' option
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
% Draw a circle
\draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
% Draw a rectangle
\draw (3,0) rectangle (5,2);
% Draw an arrow
\draw[->] (6,1) -- (8,1);
% Label some points
\node at (0,0) [below] {Center};
\node at (4,1) {Rectangle};
\node at (7,1) [above] {Arrow};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The compilation method is: XeLaTeX -> LaTeX -> DviSvgm**

### The following is my new output file:

#### my .pdf

[image]

#### my .svg

[image]

***The pdf file looks better***

---

*My question is, why does adding **dvisvgm** to the [options] make the .pdf file compiled by **xelatex** wrong? What happened to adding **dvisvgm** to the options? Is there any **other way** to generate the .pdf format and .svg format of the image at the same time? Is there an easier way?*

### Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: you need to remove the `dvisvgm` option from your tex source when you are not use dvisvgm  if you use xetex/xdvipdfmx to make a pdf it needs xdvipdf `\special` not dvisvgm `\special`

Comment: Most SVG renderers don't properly support SVG fonts as dvisvgm embeds them by default. Therefore, text elements look strange in many cases. If you call dvisvgm with option `--no-fonts` or `--font-format=woff`, you should get better looking results.

Comment: Off topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so it's not necessary to do both.